# Context is not properly initialized in pipeline

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

We are using custom layout in sitecore. After upgrading to sitecore 8.2, any webapi calls are failing because Context.Data.Site is null and Context.User is coming as default/Anonymous even though user is logged in. This failure is in below method which is called during each api calls.

```
Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Request.RequestBegin.EnsureLoggedInForPreview
```

I can see context is initialized but only some of the fields/properties are empty for this context. I am able to reinitialise Context.Data.Site with default value by patching through processor. But I need user also to be initialised properly.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried moving your custom processor into mvc.RequestBegin? This might solve your issue. I wrote a blog post about this - http://www.letsdositecore.com/sitecore-pipeline-processor-with-httpcontext-current-session/

Comment: @DoughCouto Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Request.RequestBegin.EnsureLoggedInForPreview method is already insite mvc.requestBegin and here context is not initialized propoerly. I read your blog. Can you please get me invite for sitecore slack chat room? My email id is aanataliya@gmail.com